# Как установить без PAE ядра

Tags: ubuntu, установка, ядро

При попытке установки Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS Server c CD, пишется ошибка:

```
This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU:
pae сx8

Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

Как её исправить?

Comment: включить в virtual box во вкладке настроек процессора "Enable PAE/NX" ну или в bios переключить - если это железный компьютер, ну или собрать кастомное ядро. деталей мало у вас в вопросе, что за проц, виртуальный или реальный сервер и т.д. зачем вам именно 14.04 устаревшая?

Comment: Это установка не на Virtual Box. Реальный сервер. При переходе на 16.04 были проблемы с установкой программ.
Материнская плата: VIA EPIA-ML

Comment: Процессор:VIA C3 667 MHz

Comment: никак. ну, или точнее, тебе нужно собрать ядро убунты с флагом CONFIG_X86_LONGHAUL, пересобрать дистриб с этим ядром и надеяться, что все взлетит (http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/X86_LONGHAUL.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Надеюсь, что поможет)

Comment: не советую, на самом деле, на таком проце надо будет всю систему пересобирать, подозреваю. вам в gentoo или что-нибудь типа damn small linux, скорее

Comment: Этот процессор -- разогнанный Pentium 1 (family 5) если я правильно помню, соответственно система должна быть что-то типа i586. Найдите готовый образ для Intel Quark, точно взлетит на этом проце.

Comment: http://www.smashingrobotics.com/how-to-install-debian-intel-galileo-gen-2/